# addSubview for Storyboard created views

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, addsubview

At least I think it's a basic problem. I just started working with views programmatically.

In RouteCaptureViewController.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *routeCaptureSuperView;

@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *captureImageView;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *previewImageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *captureRouteButtonView;
```

In my storyboard:

[image]

All of the outlets are properly connected, I checked.

I'm implementing addSubview in a method as such and nothing happens:

```
  [self.routeCaptureSuperView addSubview:self.captureRouteButtonView];
  [self.routeCaptureSuperView addSubview:self.captureImageView];
```

The following lines worked previously in the code:

```
[self.captureImageView removeFromSuperview];
[self.captureRouteButtonView removeFromSuperview];
```

And I know `self.routeCaptureSuperView` is not `nil` from an NSLog.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? You've added a UIView and 2 UIImageViews but they will all be blank unless you have put images/colours in them.

Comment: @Fogmeister. So I'm obviously missing something here. Take captureRouteButtonView. I added that to the storyboard and when the view initially loads it shows up. I have an IBOutlet pointer, *captureRouteButtonView, pointing to it. My thinking is that when I implement addSubview with *captureRouteButtonView it should add that view I created in Storyboard, complete with the button it contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly and you removed the views to add them again later I can make an educated guess:

In the moment you send `removeFromSuperview` to your views they get deallocated because they are declared as `weak` only.
Weak means that the property will be nil'd if the object is deallocated because the last strong relationship to that object is released.

The parent view is the object that keeps the last strong relationship to those two views.

Try to change `weak` to `strong` in the `@property` declaration of the two subviews.

Comment: This worked and helped me understand basic Objective-C dev a little more. I was simply confused and thought that since I created them in Storyboard they still existed somewhere. However, since I'm basically toggling views in this View Controller I'm thinking working with the indexes of the views in the hierarchy might be a more logical way to go.

Comment: A question about your solution: I'm still learning and have only used ARC and therefore have yet to pay close attention to memory management. If I change the `@property`'s to `strong` should I concern myself with their release/deallocation or does ARC take care of that when the View Controller is unloaded?

Comment: You don't have to release in ARC at all. However, you still must think a bit about memory management to avoid stuff like retain cycles. Stackoverflow has good questions about ARC, that explain the topic well. And btw, if you simply want to "toggle" the view you can probably just set `hidden` to YES and NO.